# jQuery timed notification onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to have the `fade` animation happen **plus** have the height of `.hideme` also growing from `0px to 30px` during the `().delay(2000)`.

Instead of `.hideme` appearing as `display: block;` on click, I want it's `height` to go from `0px to 30px` for `().delay(2000)` while also keeping the `fade` animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#post-draft1").hide();
  $("#post-button1").click(postNotification);
});

function postNotification() {
  $("#post-draft1").fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
}
```

```css
.hideme {
  background: blue;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="post-button1">Save Click</button>
<div class="hideme" id="post-draft1">This is a test div</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#post-draft1").hide();
  $("#post-button1").click(postNotification);
});

function postNotification() {
  // $("#post-draft1").fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
  $("#post-draft1").show().animate({height: '30px',opacity: 1},1000).delay(2000).animate({height: '0px',opacity: 0},1000);    

}
```

```css
.hideme {
   background: blue;
   height: 0px; 
   opacity: 0; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="post-button1">Save Click</button>
<div class="hideme" id="post-draft1">This is a test div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To animate the height you could use the `.animate()` jQuery method.

```
$('.hideme').animate({height:'30px'});
```

But first, you have to set the height to a minor value:

```
.hideme {
  background: blue;
  height: 0px;
}
```

Instead of `.delay()` you could use the callback of `fadeIn` to animate the height of `.hideme` when `fadeIn` completes:

```
$("#post-draft1").fadeIn("slow", function(){
   $('.hideme').animate({height:'30px'});
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/animate/